# Android - In which form you can save data so that we can retrieve it back in order new to old

Tags: android

I am developing android application to get feeds from GCM server. I want to show latest 25 feeds to user. 
`name-pizza, deal-125, discount-25`

```
name-burger, deal 150, discount-30
```

I want to save these items so that whenever user opens feed activity then he is presented with the latest 25 feeds - Newest at the top and oldest at the bottom. I just want to save only 25 entries. So if new entry comes then oldest will automatically gets deleted. Could you help me with it please?

Comment: implement sql database that does the job?

Comment: how can i delete more than 25 entries?

Comment: if there are more than 25 entries in the db, delete the one with the lowest id

Comment: You can store 25 entries in a small sqlite database. With a loop that runs 25 times, you could insert/update the entries.

Comment: you could also store the all the entries with the time of the insert in sqlite db, then, when in your query just order by date desc and just show the first 25 entries.